# Strings with accents coming from Mongo to LiveCode

Tags: mongodb, character-encoding, livecode

its been a while since I post in StackOverflow. I have a question for you.
When I enter "Se cambiarán los bornes" (please note the accent), in a LiveCode field, the text is properly shown, writting it to a Mongo collection also works fine, the field is saved OK in the document, I can see it using the Shell, but when retrieving the document back to LiveCode, 
the field receiving the field shows: "Se cambiarÃ­an los bornes". Trying to find the reason I found that the encoding of field "resul" is Native. 
Can you help finding the way to make this strings show the right characters?

The code:

```
on mouseUp
local theMongo, theDB, dbText, theCole, thePreg, theQuerry
put empty into field resul
put "C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe localhost:27017/" into theMongo
put "BatGar" into theDB
put "BatRegis"into theCole
put "'" & field F1 & "'" into toFind
put "{"& quote & "_id" & quote & ":" &  toFind & "}" into thePreg
put "; printjson(db.getLastError())" into dbErr
put  ".find(" & thePreg & ");"into theQuerry
put "var c=db."& theCole & theQuerry into dbText
put " while(c.hasNext())" after dbText
put " printjson(c.next())" after dbText
put dbErr after dbText
put theMongo & theDB &&  "--eval"  && quote & dbText & quote  into dbText1
put shell ( quote &dbText1 & quote) into dbResultado
put the number of lines of dbResultado into nro
put line 3 to (nro - 1) of dbResultado into field resul
if field resul is  empty   then
    Answer warning "El Documento NO ha sido encontrado.  El sistema no tiene registrada una Batería con el ID: " &  field F1  with OK
else
    Answer warning "El Documento ha sido encontrado, ID: " &  field F1  with OK
end if
```

end mouseUp

Comment: what code did you use to display the data in the field?

Comment: Please post the script used to store the string from the field in the database. Which encoding are you using for the database?

Comment: I understand that everyyhing in MOngoDB is UTF-8, so I did not specify any encoding.  The code to display the document in the LiveCode field is located in a "Find" button:

Comment: Please excuse this silly question, but how can I post the script? It does not fit here.

Comment: Just the snippet of code that actually retrieves the data and populates the field should be a start - someone may then be able to offer advice

Comment: on mouseUp
-- var declarations etc.
    put theMongo & theDB &&  "--eval"  && quote & dbText & quote  into dbText1
    put shell ( quote &dbText1 & quote) into dbResultado
    put the number of lines of dbResultado into nro
    put line 3 to (nro - 1) of dbResultado into field resul
    if field resul is  empty   then
      -- code if document not found   
    else
        Answer warning "El Documento ha sido encontrado, ID: " &  field F1  with OK
    end if
end mouseUp

Comment: Please edit the question with the formatted code.

Comment: Please read the quesion again, I edited it to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

When receiving Mongo documents in a LiveCode stack, use the function uniDecode to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16. Doing so, you get correctly accented characters.